# Resize flex item based on its content

Tags: css, flexbox

Sorry, another flexbox related question :)

I have two flex elements :

- A container (red) containing a centered div (yellow)
- A footer (blue) with an undefined height

The red container has a flex-grow:1 attribute, forcing it to take the remaining space on the screen

[image]

The issue happens when the yellow element is bigger than the screen size. I would like my red container to grow based on its content. Any idea of how I could do that ?

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body,
html {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.container {
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: red;
}

.content {
    background: yellow;
    height: 2000px;
    width: 100px;
}

.footer {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

https://codepen.io/stepinsight/pen/roRVGQ

**== EDIT ==**

Andre helped me find the answer, thanks heaps ! 
The only thing you need to change in the code above is to replace *height* by *min-height* and the *%* by *vh* for the body/html tags

```
body,
html {
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove the height property on the body element and add `height: 100%` to html

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

html { 
  height: 100% 
}

body {  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; 
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: red;
}

.content {
  background: yellow;
  height: 2000px;
  width: 100px;
}

.footer {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Corrected: https://codepen.io/ferreirandre/pen/maoVvb

Feel free to play around with the height of `.content`

Comment: Thanks Andre ! Unfortunately if I remove the height: 100% I loose the fullscreen ratio when the yellow div is smaller than the screen size : https://codepen.io/stepinsight/pen/OrqXzw

Comment: @sphax you can set `min-height: 100vh` on the container then

Comment: or if you want the footer included: `min-height: calc(100vh - 50px)`. Check my updated codepen

Comment: Thanks again ;) Good option as well, but the issue here is that my footer has an undefined height (dynamic content), so it can be 50px height but it can also be 30px or 300px..

Comment: @sphax I think that would be a different question on its own but check my updated [codepen](https://codepen.io/ferreirandre/pen/maoVvb). You can remove the height on the footer and add `flex-grow: 1` to the container in order to occupy all the available space.

Comment: Yes that's it ! Thanks heaps for your help Andre ! I compared your final codepen with my original one, and the only required change to make it work is to replace height:100% by min-height:100vh for the html/body 